# Multiindex in Pandas with multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I tried to make a multiindex DataFrame in Pandas out of two DataFrames.

```
A1 =     
     col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4 

A2 =    
    col1  col2
0     5     6
1     7     8
A_expected=   
         tb1      tb2
     col1  col2 col1 col3
0     1     3    5    6
1     2     4    7    8
```

I tried to make a new DataFrame to manage this

```
A_result=pd.DataFrame()
A_result['tb1']=A1
A_result['tb2']=A2
```

But this doesn't work. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `concat`, something like in [other similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64577500/5916727):

```
A_expected = pd.concat([A1, A2], axis=1, keys=['tb1', 'tb2'])
```

Result of `A_expected`:

```
   tb1       tb2     
  col1 col2 col1 col2
0    1    3    5    6
1    2    4    7    8
```